# Access - Missing query code in select query

Tags: ms-access

I miss some query in my database. It lost before two days and select query stays without code only `select;` rest there. It hit several select query in my databases. Simply when I open sql interface in Access there miss query code.

I restarted it several time but code is missing, its look really crazy from my point of view but haven't you experiences with it?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it's happened to me.
I think it's an office bug. I noticed that happens when trying to use many different nested query.
So, unfortunately, the only way to restore lost queries is... from a backup.
Try to semplificate the structure of your nested queries.

Comment: Hi,thank you. I thought i am crazy:) Thanks for recommendation.

Answer (score 0):

I backup all my MS ACCESS queries with a script I found, Saved me MANY times.

---

```
Dim db As Object
Dim qdf As Object

Dim ff As Long

Backup_File = gDBPATH() & "\Bin\Backup_of_All_DB_Queries-" & MonthName(Month(Now()), False) & "-" & Day(Now()) & "-" & Year(Now()) & ".txt"

Backup_File_Msg = "Backup all DB queries to: " & Backup_File & "  ?"

MyMsg = MsgBox(Backup_File_Msg, 260, "Query Backup")

If MyMsg = 6 Then

Set db = CurrentDb

ff = FreeFile()

Open Backup_File For Output As #ff

    For Each qdf In db.QueryDefs

        Print #ff, "Query: " & qdf.Name & vbCrLf

        Print #ff, "SQL: " & qdf.SQL

        Print #ff, "-----------------------------------------------" & vbCrLf

    Next qdf

Close #ff

Backup_File_Msg = "Completed backup of all DB queries to: " & Backup_File

MyMsg = MsgBox(Backup_File_Msg, vbOKOnly, "Query Backup")

End If
```